# Setting cancel flag of Window Closing event asynchronously

Tags: .net, wpf, async-await

I currently have an asynchronous event handler on the `Window.Closing` event like

```
private async void View_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
    await OnClosingAsync(e);
}
```

```
private async Task OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e) {
    foreach (BaseConfigEditViewModel viewModel in ConfigEditViewModels) {
        if (!await viewModel.IsReadyToCloseAsync()) {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
    }

    List<BaseConfigEditViewModel> tmpViewModels = new(ConfigEditViewModels);
    foreach (BaseConfigEditViewModel viewModel in tmpViewModels) {
        viewModel.Close();
    }
}
```

```
public async Task<bool> IsReadyToCloseAsync() {
    if (await GetHasChangedAsync()) {
        switch (MessageBox.Show($"{Header} has changed. Save changes?", "Info", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxImage.Question)) {
            case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
                await SaveAsync();
                return true;
            case MessageBoxResult.Cancel:
                return false;
            case MessageBoxResult.No:
                return true;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

where the `e.Cancel` flag gets set in an asynchronous method that is awaited in the handler.

As the event handler itself doesn't return a task, yet is async, to my knowledge this implies a "dumb" fire-and-forget mechanism for the window who invokes the event.

How come it still knows how long to wait for the event to be handled by all subscribers? It would need to await the handling in order to know whether some subscriber has set the Cancel flag, doesn't it?

Edit: Included the whole call chain across various classes up to the async methods that perform various DB calls.

Comment: I would not necessarily say dangerous code. But think outside the box. Use an If statement to decide the behavior. If conditions met  then do what you want if not then do what you want. It's a little unconventional but if it works it can be something that's a quick fix til you find a more suitable fix.

Comment: My condition, whether to cancel or not, itself is based on the results of asynchronous DB calls @CampNerd. Sure, I can implement workarounds to not make that async, but that isn't my question.
I mean, what I have implemented is working, even if I add an arbitrary Task.Delay in the async method. My question is mainly "why is it working?".

Comment: that's the beauty of coding. Not knowing is half the coding. If it works don't fix it.. number one rule. To tell you, "Why it works the way it does" is the same as "does a tree make a sound in the woods when it falls when no one is around." In my 20 years of coding I learned not to second guess things that work... But the fact is a simple answer of I don't know the Why it works, but I would say something in the background is still firing a function or method. I would not stress to much on it. Half the developers that created coding probably doesn't know.

Comment: ... then count me as one of those few developers that like to know why something works ;)
There could be something I am misunderstanding about how events are handled WPF internally or how `async void` methods behave. So an answer might be useful knowledge...
I removed the last paragraph in my question to not confuse. This isn't about me needing a fix, but an explanation.

Comment: When an event is fired it sends a signal. Think of a light switch. The switch is open and the electric current flows to the bulb. The light bulb ceases to function when the light switch is off (circuit is closed). So the event will only fire a signal to close when all other signals are closed. As long as the signal flows then it stays active... That's about the best I can simplify it off the top of my head. But the signal could be from numerous sources that will close the event. Threads, and stuff. That's where disposing comes in to play.

Comment: It is relevant to know your OnClosingAsync implementation.

Comment: And what is GetHasChangedAsync looking like?

Comment: I don't really get, why this is relevant to the question. It executes some query against a DB and reacts on the result. Every code path hits an OpenAsync and ExecuteScalarAsync, if that's what you are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this is not reproducible in a smaller application. While in my app even an arbitrary Task.Delay doesn't cause the canceling to file, i.e. a handler like

```
private async void View_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
    await Task.Delay(100);

    // ...

    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

a similar construct in a simple app without anything else fails to cancel.

Hence, it is actually dangerous to do what I was doing, as the dumb fire mechanism of the async void event doesn't guarantee that the source knows every subscriber had it's chance to cancel.

As to the app I am working on; seems like some other synchronous components of the app I am part of take long enough to handle their synchronous closing-Event, so it was never a problem, even with said arbitrary Task.Delay.